# How can i filter and sorty my WordPress Users Table by a Custom value from another table?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using "The Newsletter Plugin" for my WordPress instance. To see the newsletter lists each user is assigned to, I added a column to the users table where the lists should be listed. That is working out so far.
Now i want to add a custom filter above to query only users in a specific list and sort the new column alphabetically

I managed to add a new filter above

```
add_action( 'manage_users_extra_tablenav', 'render_custom_filter_options' );
function render_custom_filter_options() {


    // Get the Newsletter instance to receive the subscribers and list names
    $newsletter = Newsletter::instance();
    $subscriber = $newsletter->get_user(get_userdata($user_id)->user_email);
    $lists = get_option("newsletter_subscription_lists");
    
    // Remove additional array entries
    $pattern = "/list_[0-9]+$/";
    foreach ($lists as $key => $entry) {
        if(!preg_match($pattern,$key) || empty($entry)) {
            unset($lists[$key]);
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form method="GET">
        <select name="group">
            <option value="">Gruppen filtern</option>
            <?php foreach ( $lists as $value => $label ): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET["group"]) && $value == $_GET["group"]) {echo "selected";} ?>><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Filter">
    </form>
    
    <?php
}
```

This alone - of course - doesn't filter anything. So I need to add a user query - but as far as i can tell i can only query values from the usermeta table.

The subscribers are in database table "wp_newsletter" and can be matched by email address or userid.
The lists the users are assigned to are columns in this table, i.e. "list_1" => 1; "list_2"=>0.

Is there a way to write a wp user query to return only users in a specific list, if the list is not saved in the usermeta? Can the column be somehow sorted alphabetically?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter and sort the WordPress Users table by a custom value from some another table, you will need to use a custom query and join the tables together based on a common value. In this case, you can join the `wp_users` table with the `wp_newsletter` table based on the user's email address or user ID.

```
function wp_custom_user_query( $user_query ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['group'] ) && $_GET['group'] != '' ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $group = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['group'] );
      
        $join_clause = " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}newsletter AS n ON n.user_id = {$wpdb->prefix}users.ID";
        $where_clause = $wpdb->prepare( " AND n.list_%d = 1", $group );
        $orderby_clause = "ORDER BY n.list_{$group} ASC, {$wpdb->prefix}users.display_name ASC";
        $user_query->query_from .= $join_clause;
        $user_query->query_where .= $where_clause;
        $user_query->query_orderby = $orderby_clause;
    }
    return $user_query;
}

add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'wp_custom_user_query' );
```

This filter joins the `wp_users` and `wp_newsletter` tables based on the user's email address or user ID. It then adds a query condition to filter on the specified group and sorts the results by the user column (list name) in ascending order, followed by the user's display name.